# Apollo GraphQL Mutation (Object Argument)

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, apollostack

So, I'm trying to design my Apollo server. I wanted to create a mutation with an object as a parameter.

Here is a snippet of my schema which somehow caused the problem:

[image]

I thought it was syntactically correct, but I ran into this error:

{"errors":[{"message":"Expected Input type."}]}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to declare INPUT_OBJECT to be an input type:

```
input INPUT_OBJECT {
  field1: String,
  # etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're a life saver.

Comment: @helfer may I have 2 definitions for INPUT_OBJECT? one `type` and other `input` with the same name (if also I want to query)? Or should I declare one for query and other for mutation?